# Enabling hover popup window for feature IDs in Mapview package for R

Tags: r, leaflet, popup, mapview

I've been working with interactive mapping within R for a while now and most of my experience lies in Leaflet (mostly the R package, but also a bit in Javascript). I just recently delved into `mapview` as an alternative and have a quick question about enabling the hover popup windows.

As you can see in [this example](http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/basics/basics.html) with polygons, when you move your mouse over each polygon, a small popup window appears with each feature ID. The vector data description states:

> in case you have the latest version of leaflet installed the map will
>   also have a scale bar in the bottom left corner and provide labels of
>   feature IDs if you hover over the features.

I have both Leaflet and Leaflet for R updated on my computer, yet this hover feature is not activated. The scale bar is also not shown. I used the `mapview` example of gadmCHE, as you'll see in the image below:

[image]

Does anyone know if this "latest version of leaflet" refers to leaflet.js or the R package `leaflet`? I just downloaded Leaflet 1.0.0-rc3 [here](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) and also made sure that I updated the `leaflet` package, so I'm not sure where to go from here to enable that hover/scalebar feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install the latest version of `leaflet` (`R` package). 
Try:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
```

### Update 1:

Try installing the development version of `mapview`

```
devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")
```

That worked for me.

[image: example]

Comment: yes! Loading in the development version yielded the results I wanted. Hover windows are now in working order. :) Thanks!